# How can I run functions of dbms_output as non-admin?

Tags: oracle, dbms-output

I have XE on my computer, using  Oracle Database 18c. Earlier, I was able to execute function `dbms_output.put_line();` even I logged in as sysadmin or with default role. Now, I only can run `dbms_output.put_line()` when I am logged in as sysadmin/sysdba. As a default user, I get the following message:

```
PLS-00201: identifier ‘DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE’ must be declared
```

I tried to add privilege to execute `dbms_output` with command
`grant execute on DBMS_OUTPUT to username;`, however, I got this message when I execute a command including `dbms_output.put_line()`:

```
ORA-04067: not executed, package body "PERFSTAT.DBMS_OUTPUT" does not exist
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "PERFSTAT.DBMS_OUTPUT"
```

Using sqlplus, I get the following error as default user:

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE' must be declared
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you, perhaps, create a synonym while trying to fix your problem - which does originally seem to have just been a typo? What is 'the default user'?

Comment: @AlexPoole, 'default user' wants to mean 'non-admin user'.  
It can be because I'm reading a book written by Tom Kyte, where there was a part we – setting up Statspack – create a schema named 'Perfstat'.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you misnamed it:

```
No : DBMS_OUPUT.PUT_LINE      (not "ouput" but "output")
Yes: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
```

---

As of the 2nd message; well, this: `PERFSTAT.DBMS_OUTPUT` doesn't make sense, PERFSTAT doesn't own that package. It is called just as

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Hello');
end;
/
```

and works for any user, no special grants required.

Comment: I wrote code you added here but I still get the `perfstat`-error. :/

Comment: You do? How come, if I never mentioned PERFSTAT in code I posted?

Comment: You can try calling `sys.dbms_output.put_line('Hello');`. If that works, maybe you created a broken synonym for dbms_output to perfstat.dbms_output.